# Why I can't set the two top corners rounded in a UIView inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can't set the two top corners rounded in a UIView inside a UITableViewCell, i.e.

[image: UITableViewCell xib]

```
 let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: containerView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft, .TopRight, ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
 let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: maskPath)
 maskLayer.frame = containerView.bounds
 maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
 maskLayer.masksToBounds = true
 containerView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

And when I run the app I get this:

[image: UITableViewCell runtime]

I add background color to my custom `UIView` and background color to the cell content view just for demonstrative purpose and I added more value to the right constraint to show it doesn't work:

[image: UIView with background color]

But If a create an `UIView` alone in an empty  `UIViewController` it works perfectly.

I found when I set the fixed width adding a width constraint it works but I want the width size will be set dynamically (to work with all of the devices and orientations), adding trailing constraint is when it doesn't work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: add `maskLayer.masksToBounds =YES`

Comment: @iphonic It didn't work

Comment: I'm with Anthony Rn on this one. I bet your layer and thus your view is off screen right. You're also masking the `containerView` by that layer, so if your `containerView` is off your `maskLayer` is going to be off too.

Comment: At which point of the rendering process are you setting this: `maskLayer.frame = containerView.bounds` ? It is possible that `containerView.bounds` doesn't have the width you think it should at that time.

Comment: @Aaron I add this code on the method: `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`

Comment: That's weird, for sure. Why are you masking the `containerView`? I bet something is up with the `mask`.

Comment: Instead of masking can you just give the path to the layer and then set the layer on the containerView? Like this: `containerView.layer = maskLayer`? Forget the mask entirely?

Comment: @Aaron I can't set the custom view layer directly because is a read-only property. I found when I set the fixed width adding a width constraint it works but I want the width size will be set dynamically (to work with all of the devices and orientations), adding trailing constraint is when it doesn't work.

Comment: That's right `layer` can't be set that way. That you can achieve this by setting a fixed width constraint is a clue that the `mask` layer, who gets its frame from the `containerView` doesn't have the correct width at that time.

Comment: If you want the size be dynamic, just add your width constraint again and set it a value (whatever the value). Then connect the width constraint to your UIViewController. Then you could just adjust the constant of your width constraint in the viewDidLoad() method for example with the width of your UITableView and then you will have a dynamic width. Just like that :

`@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraintOfYourView: NSLayoutConstraint!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//...
    widthConstraintOfYourView.constant = self.tableview.frame.size.width
  }`

Comment: @AnthonyRoani I can't connect the width constraint with my UITableViewController because my custom view is on a UITableViewCell class. By the way, I can't have a width constraint with a leading and trailing constraint at the same time. It will be tricky to recalculate the width when the orientation will change.

Comment: Connect it to your `UITableViewCell`, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in your UITableViewController you can do : `cell.widthConstraintOfYourView.constant = ...` and no need to have leading and trailing : instead set center horizontally / center vertically constraints to your UIView

Answer (score 0):

I think it's working but what happens is that the width of your UIView is too large. (Bigger than your cell) so you don't see the right corner. Try to set some constraints on your UIView inside your cell and I think it will work

Comment: I set a width contraint with 100 of constant to the UIView and it didn't work

Comment: Please can you set a backgroundColor to your UIView and then take a screenshot of it, So I can see the 2 top corners of your UIView. Because for now I only see the left top corner on your screenshot. Also, try to use the debug view hierarchy tool and then click on the button which displays hided views, so you will see if there is a problem with the size of your UIView

Comment: I add a new imagen to the question with my custom view and the content view cell with background color

Comment: You can try to see you view hierarchy: Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy